# Check if SASS function argument is a list with one or more items

Tags: css, sass

I need to build a function where the argument passed to the function is a variable list which in some cases may contain only one item, like following:

```
$example-list-1: grey 20;              // this is a single list item
$example-list-2: grey 20, grey 30;     // this is a list with two items separated by comma

@function box-shadow($params-list) {
    // ...
    // here comes the problem
    @each $item in $params-list {
        // if $example-list-1 is passed as argument it will be considered a list with two items!
    }
}
```

In order to avoid that problem I need to perform a check to see what kind of list was passed as argument, and in case of a list with one item I have to fake it like having multiple items, like this:

```
@function box-shadow($params-list) {
    @if (params-list has only one item) {
        $params-list: append($params-list, null, comma);
    }
    // problem solved
    @each $item in $params-list {
        // perform the magic
    }
    @return $result;
}
```

So, the question is how to check if params-list has only one item? Or, is there any workaround to solve this problem?

**EDIT:**
I found sort of a viable hack, to add an empty list item separated by comma, like this:

```
$example-list-1: grey 20, ();
```

The thing is that I can use this hack just by manually edit the variables, but not programatically! So the question remains...

Answer (score 0):

I found a function inside the docs, it can be used to perform the check if separator is comma, and if not the list is rebuilded as a comma separated list:

```
@use "sass:list";
//...
@function box-shadow($params-list) {
    // check if separator is comma, if not rebuild the list
    @if list.separator($params-list) != comma {
        $new-list: ();
        $params-list: append($new-list, $params-list, comma);
        @debug list.separator($params-list);
    }
    // loop now works as expected
    @each $item in $params-list {
        // code
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I also wrote two helper functions, can be used when a list is expected in some format:

```
// convert to comma separated list
@function comma-separated-list($list) {
    @if list.separator($list) != comma {
        $new-list: ();
        $list: append($new-list, $list, comma);
        // @debug list.separator($list);
    }
    @return $list;
}

// convert to space separated list
@function space-separated-list($list) {
    @if list.separator($list) != space {
        $new-list: ();
        $list: append($new-list, $list, space);
        // @debug list.separator($list);
    }
    @return $list;
}
```